# If an $n \times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, does each of its eigenspaces have to be $1$-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My book writes the following statement:

> For a square matrix $A$ of order $n$ to be diagonalizable, the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces must be equal to $n$. One way this can happen is when $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

I'm a little confused on the last sentence. Are they trying to say that if $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues, then it must be the case that each eigenspace is $1$-dimensional? Couldn't it be possible for one or more of the eigenspaces to be $2$-dimensional or three-dimensional, etc?

Comment: The geometric multiplicity is always at most the algebraic multiplicity. If there are $n$ distinct eigenvalues, each has algebraic multiplicity of 1.

Comment: Put it another way, eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are linearly independent. So, the sum of dimensions of eigenspaces of a matrix must be bounded above by the dimension of the vector space.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of the eigenspaces corresponding to different eigenvalues is always $\{0\}$. Indeed if $x \in E_m$, the eigenspace of $m$ and $x \in E_n$  then we have $Ax = mx$ and $Ax = nx$ so $(m-n)x = 0$ so, since $m \neq n$, $x$ must be $0$. Now let $d_i$ be the dimension of the eigenspace of eigenvalue $m_i$ with $i \in \{1 \ldots n\}$ then the only way $d_1+d_2 + \ldots +d_n = n$ is when all the $d_i = 1$.

Comment: It is not enough, really, that the intersection of the eigenspaces be zero: you need them to be in direct sum for this to work.

Comment: I was only responding to the OP''s concern that the dimensions could be $>1$.

Comment: Well, the dimensions could all be equal to 2 and the intersection zero. For example, the intersection of  the three coordinate planes in $R^3$ is zero.

Comment: I thought to have proven  that for **any two** eigenspaces their intersection was zero.?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^4$ consider for each $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ the subspace $V_\lambda=\langle e_1+\lambda e_2,e_3+\lambda e_4\rangle$. You can easily check that all of these subspaces have dimension $2$ and that their pairwise intersections are all trivial.

Comment: If you want to prove that $n$ subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space have dimension $1$ it is not enough to show that each of their pairwise intersections is trivial, independently of how much bold you use. In order to have the equation $d_1+\cdots+d_n=n$ that you want, you have to show that the subspaces are in direct sum, as I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it has n **distinct** eigenvalues then yes, each eigenspace must have dimension one. This is because each one has at least dimension one, there is n of them and sum of dimensions is n, if your matrix is of order n it means that the linear transformation it determines goes from and to vector spaces of dimension n.

If you have 2 equal eigenvalues then no, you may have a eigenspace with dimension greater than one.

Comment: But even if A is nxn, couldn't you have more than n eigenvectors? Like let's say A is 3x3, couldn't you have two two-dimensional eigenspaces? It's not like I'm talking about having a four-dimensional eigenspace, just two two-dimensional ones

Comment: You must remember that each pair of eigenspaces is "disjoint" so if your space is of dimension 3 you cannot have 2 spaces of dimensions 2 without them intersecting in other point than zero and then not being disjoint. To see why they are disjoint remember that the eigenvalues determine a partition of the vector space.

Comment: Thank you, can you expand on why the eigenvalues determine a partition of the vector space? I'm afraid I don't know what a partition of a vector space is.

Comment: Let $a_1, \dots , a_n $ be the eigenvalues, the eigenspace associated to $a_i $ is $Ker (f-a_i I)$, now we have to see that 2 eigenspaces only intersect in zero, lets suppose $v \in Ker (f-a_i I)\cap Ker (f-a_j I) $ then $(f-a_i I)(v)=f (v)-a_i v)=0=(f- a_j)(v)=f (v)-a_j v $ ths implies that $v=0$ because qe are supposing $a_i $ is distinct from $a_j $ then we have that different eigenvalues give different eigenspaces and that 2 eigenspaces from different eigenvectors have intersection zero. A partition means that it divides the vector space in disjoint pieces. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jonathaniui, it is not enough to show that the pairwise intersections are trivial to be ble to conclude. See the comments on Marc´s answer.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that, dim(U+V) = dim(U) + dim(V) - dim(U ∩ V)

If a matrix A has 'n' distinct Eigenvalues, then the matrix A has 'n' Linearly Independent Eigen Vectors.

Let the eigenspace formed by λi is Ei.

A vector x can not belong to two different Eigenspaces. And thus making the intersection of the eigenspaces trivial. Thus, summing the eigenspaces corresponding to 'n' distinct eigenspaces:

dim(E1+E2+E3+...+En)=dim(E1)+dim(E2)+dim(E3)+...+dim(En)

=> n = dim(E1)+dim(E2)+...+dim(En)

And since dim(Ei)>0, it follows that dim(Ei) is indeed equal to 1.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).